# Why return req.on helps to fix the bug?

Tags: node.js

I have been taking nodejs course online and couldn't understand the following solution to a bug. Given this code that we wrote to learn the basics - why it is necessary to use the return ( the bolded one)? without it the code doesn't work.

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');


const server = http.createServer((req, res) => 
{
    const url = req.url;
    const method = req.method;
    if(url === '/')
    {
        res.write('<html>');
        res.write('<head><title> Enter Message </title></head>');
        res.write('<body><form action = "/message" method = POST> <input type = "text" name = "message"><button type = "submit"> Send </button></form><body>');
        res.write('</html>');
        return res.end();
    }

    if (url === '/message' && method === 'POST')
    {
        const body = [];
        req.on('data', (chunk) => {
            console.log(chunk);
            body.push(chunk);
        });
        
        return req.on('end', () => { // why return this?
            const praseBody = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
            console.log(praseBody);
            const message = praseBody.split('=')[1];
            fs.writeFile('message.txt', message, (err) => {
                res.statusCode = 302;
                res.setHeader('Location', '/');
                return res.end();
            });
        });
    }
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.write('<html>');
    res.write('<head><title> My First Page </title></head>');
    res.write('<body><h1> Hello </h1></html>');
    res.write('</html>');
    res.end();
});


server.listen(3000);
```

Comment: What happens without `return` btw? Do you see the `My First Page` page?

Answer (score 1):

**It's not a bug.**

If you don't use `return` the rest of the code will be processed, which is not what you want.

If your code looked like bellow the order in which the code is processed is marked with numbers 1 to 3

```
if (url === '/message' && method === 'POST')
{
// 1 -----------
    const body = [];
    req.on('data', (chunk) => {
        console.log(chunk);
        body.push(chunk);
    });
    // notice no return here
    req.on('end', () => { // why return this?
        const praseBody = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
        console.log(praseBody);
        const message = praseBody.split('=')[1];
        fs.writeFile('message.txt', message, (err) => {
            // 3 ---------
            // this would be called after res.end bellow in step 2
            // but the connection has already been closed so the bellow code will fail
            res.statusCode = 302;
            res.setHeader('Location', '/');
            return res.end();
        });
    });
}
// 2 ---------
// with the return this code would not run
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
res.write('<html>');
res.write('<head><title> My First Page </title></head>');
res.write('<body><h1> Hello </h1></html>');
res.write('</html>');
// this would be called 1st and above again. 
res.end();
```

You could simply use `else` statement to avoid calling res.end multiple times

```
if (url === '/message' && method === 'POST') {
    ....
} else {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.write('<html>');
    res.write('<head><title> My First Page </title></head>');
    res.write('<body><h1> Hello </h1></html>');
    res.write('</html>');
    res.end();
}
```

Comment: To make sure I understand - the return here works differently from python?
In python, if I write a return inside an If block and then have some code after it, the code will be executed, but in here the return in the If block will "exit" the entire response?

Comment: Well it depends. The `return` will stop execution of the code within its scope. For example the `return` in the fs.writeFile callback does nothing because its scope is the callback function and it is the last thing in that function. Another example: `console.log('before'); return; console.log('after');` the `after` will never be printed since it's essentially unreachable